# Php genarate data from table 1 to table 2 but will duplicate after 1000 rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, slice

I would like to create a function to generate a random rank. I have a member table call `t1_user`, I would like to `ORDER BY RAND()` from `t1_user` when my second table `t2_rank` is empty.

My `t1_user` table have 5400 rows of data, so I would like to split the data like every 500 row data then `REPLACE INTO`. I am using `Discuz!` template language.

My `t1_user` data (5400 record+, no duplicate)

```
+--------------------+
| id      | name     |
+--------------------+
| 1       | abc      |
| 2       | hahaha   |
| 3-999.....         |
| 1000    | abcdef   |
| 1001    | ohyeah   |
| 1002    | nci      |
----------------------
```

After I running my code, will insert below data to my `t2_rank` table

```
+---------+----------+--------+
| id      | name     | rank   |
+-----------------------------+
| 1       | abc      | 1      |
| 2       | hahaha   | 2      |
| 1000    | abcdef   | 1000   | //until here is fine
| 1001    | abc      | 1001   | //wrong, will insert data of row1 and continue data of row2...
| 1002    | hahaha   | 1002   |
+-----------------------------+
```

My current coding as below.

```
$checkfirst = DB::result_first("SELECT count(*) cnt FROM ".DB::table('t2_rank').""); //template language DB::
if($checkfirst == 0){
    $s = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('t1_user')." ORDER BY RAND();");
    $x = 1;
    foreach($s as $su){
        $newdata[$x] = '('.$x.','.$id.')';
        $x++;
    }
        
    $pagesplit = 500;//500 row split
    $firstpage = 0;
    $tpp = $pagesplit;
    $runningtime = ceil(count($s)/$pagesplit);      

    for($y=1;$y<$runningtime;$y++){
        $genewdata = array_slice($newdata, $firstpage, $tpp);
        $tobeupdate = implode(',',$genewdata);
        DB::query("REPLACE INTO ".DB::table('t2_rank')." (rank,id) VALUES ".$tobeupdate."");
                    
        $firstpage = $firstpage+$pagesplit;
        $tpp = $tpp+$pagesplit;
        if($tpp >= count($s)){
            $tpp = count($s);
        }
    }
}
```

May I know what wrong of my code? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to step through your data updating 500 rows at a time. Your code for doing so is rather complex. That way you loose track of what is going on. You seem to be mixing up the `$tpp` and `$firstpage` variables. No wonder, given their names. Here is my proposal:

```
$totalRowCount = count($s);
$replaceCount = 500;
for ($offset = 0; $offset < $totalRowCount; $offset = $offset + $replaceCount) {
    $replaceData = array_slice($newdata, $offset , $replaceCount);
    DB::query("REPLACE INTO " . DB::table('t2_rank') . 
              " (rank,id) VALUES " . implode(',', $replaceData));
}
```

I cannot test this, but I think you can see what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, actually I am wrong understanding of `array_slice()`, I thought `$offset` and `$replaceCount` is the range I want to slice, but actually `$replaceCount` is quantity (how much) I would like to get start from `$offset`. Thank you.